# Javascript, how to implement a "blocking" function called from multiple workers

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web-worker

I would appreciate some ideas/help for a decent implementation to this problem.

I have a functionA called from different workers. The function in fact makes a AJAX request to my server (really it is the same query for any of the workers).

What I want is only the first time the functionA is invoked make the request and block all the other calls until the server request finished and return the value to all the workers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could do that with a Promise

Comment: Unbind then rebind on success?

Comment: by the way, using a Promise it wouldn't be blocking, it'd just be asynchronous done right :p

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want to block in JavaScript, you're doing something wrong. To solve your problem, you'd need a means of thread synchronization. There's no such thing in JavaScript.

Your only option to do that is to ensure that your request can only be dispatched from one thread.

For example, ensure that only the main GUI thread or a specific shared worker is responsible for loading the request. The solution: **All other workers will send message in order to query the request and receive message when the data is loaded.**

You provided no code with your question so I am not providing code either.

Comment: Synchronisation through a dedicated [actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) is still synchronisation :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
function load() {
    // make AJAX and return a promise
}

var promise; // create a promise and resolve it.
function loadBlocked() {
  return (promise = promise.then(load, load));
}
```